# Bootstrap Navbar with Logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so i've been working with bootstrap headers with a Logo before the "**Brand**" but i seems that the whole navbar won't resize, refer to screenshot below

-[image]

As you can see the whole navbar won't adjust to the height of the new "**Brand**". 
here is a code snippet on my navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/samplelogo.png" alt="CansoX" class="logo" /> &nbsp; Conquer and Explore </a>
        </div>

         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Anyone knew this problem please do give me some pointers :)

Comment: can you share your css for above code. codepen or jsfiddle will be more helpfull.

Comment: only css im using is the boostrap one

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the height attribute? like this:

```
.navbar-brand{
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Ya, you would think right? Bootstrap has a lot of pre-loaded styles on it.  Maybe if you were rolling out your own navbar, it would work like that.

Comment: You would probably have to add JavaScript to cause the height to automatically adjust.

Comment: Maybe someday the W3C will add a CSS standard that allows the height of elements to adjust automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `class="clearfix"` to wrap logo and dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening, is that your logo is being float left. (most likely) --- So, when things are floated left, it's container no longer understands that crazy new world of positioning unless it too is floated. So it doesn't know what size to be. A quick fix would be `overflow: hidden` or a border works sometimes too. but that could have unexpected consequences down the road. I best think to do would be to use a micro-clear-fix - which I'm sure is built into crap-strap somewhere. So you can add the class in html on whatever box is collapsing, or if you are using LESS or SASS you can extend that class in you SCSS or whatever to keep your HTML cleaner.